# Как проверить значение в sqlite3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, sqlite3

у меня тут появилась проблема, мне нужно проверить значение в sqlite. Я делаю бота через aiogram, которому нужно проверять, есть ли в таблице id пользователя а если нет, то добавить его. У меня получился такой код -

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    for row in c:
        if row['chat_id'] == message['from']['id']:
            await message.reply('test: no')
        elif row['chat_id'] != message['from']['id']:
            data = [message['from']['id'], str(message['from']['username'])]
            c.execute("INSERT INTO имя таблицы VALUES ?,?", data)
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
            await message.reply('test: ok')
```

Sqlite3 и Python Ошибки не нашли, но и код не работает как нужно.
Сможете помочь? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Причём тут sqlite?

Comment: Я исправил вопрос, прочитайте ещё раз пожалуйста

Comment: Проверку можно сделать так: ```f'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id == {user_id}'``` если этот запрос что-то возвращает, значит такой юзер есть, иначе добавляете в БД

Comment: @Nobody это плохой совет, ну стоит использовать интерполяцию строк для формирования sql-запросов.

Comment: Ребят (@Nobody , @Sergey Gornostaev), я так и не понял что мне делать с этим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот вам пример для понимания логики:

```
# postgresql
def search_db_users(id_tlgrm):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=db_name, user=db_user, password=db_password, host=db_host)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT id_tlgrm FROM users WHERE id_tlgrm = %s", (id_tlgrm,))
    idt = cursor.fetchone()
    if idt is None:
        return None
    else:
        return idt[0]


# sqlite
def search_id_tlg(id_tlgrm):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    cursor = conn.execute("SELECT id_tlgrm FROM users WHERE id_tlgrm=?", (id_tlgrm,)).fetchone()
    if cursor is None:
        conn.close()
        return None
    else:
        conn.close()
        idt = cursor[0]
        return idt


# pytelegrambotapi
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    if message.chat.id == search_db_users(message.chat.id):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'где-то я тебя видел')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'будем знакомы')
```

функция `search_id_tlg()` принимает Telgram id - `search_id_tlg(message.chat.id)`
запрос `SELECT id_tlgrm FROM users WHERE id_tlgrm=?` = выбрать `id_tlgrm` из `users` где `id_tlgrm`=`id_tlgrm`:

- в первом случае (`SELECT id_tlgrm`) - колонка
- во втором (`WHERE id_tlgrm`) - искомое (если имеется в БД)
- в третьем (`(id_tlgrm,)`) - то что ищем в БД, `message.chat.id`

Comment: Я всё-таки не очень понял, код выдаёт ошибку, можете подробнее объяснить?

Comment: какую ошибку? вы изменили код под sqlite?

Comment: В том и проблема, я не знаю где мне что изменить, что-бы получить нормальный питоновский sqlite. 
Ещё я не очень понял, что это у вас в коде за id_tlgrm???
Если можно, то переведите в sqlite:)

Comment: исправил свой ответ. добавил пример для `sqlite` и постарался объяснить что да как в запросе и что же такое `id_tlgrm`

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_message(message: types.Message):
      users_id = str(message.from_user.id)
      conn = sqlite3.connect('*название базы*')
      cur = conn.cursor()
      cur.execute(
          "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (users_id,))
      info = cur.fetchone()[0]
      if info == 0:
         # выполняем если id нема в базе
      else:
         # выполняем если id есть в базе
```